# Page Up/Down on Adobe reader on mac

Tags: keyboard, adobe

When a new document is opened, the Left/Right arrows work properly for Page Up / Page Down.

However after having browsed in the document, it frequently occurs that Left/Right arrows only move single *characters* to the left/right.

I have not been able to discover

- what sequence of browsing causes the behavior to change
- how to revert the behavior back to full page incrementing

Tips appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After opening a new pdf the cursor doesn't really exist and depending on your settings Left/Right arrows work properly for Page Up / Page Down.

As soon as you move the cursor into the document you will navigate inside your pdf and Page Up / Page Down won't work anymore with the Left/Right arrow keys.

To restore the previous behavior just click on the dark grey background.
That's a bit difficult if View -> Zoom is set to 'Fit Width', because the gap between document and frame is very small and hard to hit with the cursor.

[image: gap]

Comment: Clicking on the dark background does the trick. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Press the esc key to navigate out of the document edit/select mode. The Left/Right arrow keys should then work again the same as before.